# Android - How to make push-notifications in android

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification

I want to notify android users(students) whenever they got failing grades. I tried using Firebase notification, but what I can do about it is to manually type messages in my firebase account and send it to users. I want to send notification to specific users automatically depending on the condition in my codes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For that, you need to write a script in any scripting language like php. And you can automate this thing when some one uploads the result. That script will tell firebase to send push to specific use with pre-typed message.

Comment: do you have an idea how to connect php to firebase??

Comment: You need to create app server https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server.html.  Conection from php to firebase is just HTTP request (or XMPP);

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to start with [Firebase Notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/)

*Less code and reliable*

You can start with code sample
https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/#android
and find the **Cloud Messaging** sample

You can also archive this by using [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) that will provide data changed listener every time data is added/updated. And you can take this advantage of the listener to notify your *Notification* in Android